# Cordova plugin to detect internet connection

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

my cordova app requires internet connection for some actions.
i am using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information to get an event whenever the app goes online or offline.
It works well with Mobile Data, but for Wifi, it acts a bit strange.
Whether my wifi is connected to the internet or not, it reports that i am online in both cases.

The behavior that i am expecting is to say i am online only when the wifi is connected to the internet.
i am running ionic framework, angularjs, cordova 3.5.1, and using an Android, Galaxy S3 for testing.

Comment: I think the Plugin can just detect whether you are connected to a wifi network or not. It doesn't make a difference if your wifi-network is connected to the internet or not. The Plugin has to send a package to a server, and get an answer for detecting if you're online or offline. Maybe you are able to build such a feature on your own with javascript by pinging google for example but... i don't know, in what relationship this stands to applicable law

Comment: i think i get the direction here. i need internet connectivity to access my own api, so i can ping my own api to check for internet connectivity.

Answer (score 6):

The plugin does not detect if the user has access to the Internet, but only if the user is on a network. Since your phone is on a WiFi network even though the WiFi network doesn't have access to the Internet, the plugin is performing as designed.

In order to test connectivity, you must always attempt the request -- this is the only way to truly know if the device has Internet access. So if you're trying to reach `www.google.com`, you have to attempt the request and handle any errors that result. The only benefit to having the network plugin in place is that you have a little more information about whether or not it is even worth attempting the request in the first place -- if the device is not connected to any network, you know there is little benefit in trying the request.

> If there is no route, your request should fail nearly immediately. If there is some other issue, your request may time out instead. Be sure to indicate some progress to the user in the case of a long request, since time outs can take several seconds (or minutes) to occur.

If your app needs to target specific hosts, those would be the same hosts you'd use to verify connectivity. If your app targets generic hosts (or user-entered hosts), test with the specific host to test connectivity.

- Don't assume that because a device can reach one host that it means it can reach another, either -- some networks may block certain hosts while allowing access to others.
- Don't test with a host that isn't part of the actual request, especially if it is one you don't control. That is, if you want to test if the user can reach `www.example.com`, don't ping `www.google.com`. Your attempt might be taken as a malicious attack, especially if your app became popular.

One other tip:

> DO check the network type to see if you need to limit data (in the case of cellular networks)
>    but DON'T assume the network type can be used to indicate data transfer speeds -- just because you're on a 4G network does not mean that you will be guaranteed fast data transfer. Of course, the same applies to WiFi.

Comment: Thanks Kerri, this is comprehensive ! I will implement it the way you suggested exactly. I thought there could be a way for another plugin to detect internet connectivity, rather than network connectivity.